# Connectivity issues from App Engine to CloudSQL using Private IP and Serverless VPC Access

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, serverless, google-vpc

I am doing a PoC to connect from `Google App Engine` to `CloudSQL instance` running with `Private IP`  on a `SharedVPC` . The sample application for testing is from
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/cloud-sql/mysql/sqlalchemy/README.md

My `Serverless VPC Connector Range` is as follows

```
 $ gcloud compute networks vpc-access connectors list --region=us-central1
  CONNECTOR_ID       REGION       NETWORK          IP_CIDR_RANGE    MIN_THROUGHPUT  MAX_THROUGHPUT  STATE
  testserverlessvpc  us-central1  kube-shared-vpc  192.168.60.0/28  200             300             READY
```

`Private IP Range` is as follows

```
     $ gcloud compute addresses list --global --filter="purpose=VPC_PEERING"
  NAME                 ADDRESS/RANGE     TYPE      PURPOSE      NETWORK           REGION  SUBNET  STATUS
 cloudsqltestrangenew  10.0.100.0/20    INTERNAL  VPC_PEERING  kube-shared-vpc                   RESERVED
```

`MySQL` instance is as follows

```
$ gcloud sql instances list
 NAME       DATABASE_VERSION  LOCATION       TIER         PRIMARY_ADDRESS  PRIVATE_ADDRESS  STATUS
 mysql2           MYSQL_5_7         us-central1-b  db-f1-micro  -            10.0.100.5       RUNNABLE
```

`app.standard.yaml` is as follows

```
 runtime: python37

 service: appcentralpri
 env_variables:
     CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME: projectname:us-central1:mysql2
     DB_USER: guestdb
     DB_PASS: password
     DB_NAME: testdb
     DB_HOST: 10.0.100.5:3306

     vpc_access_connector:
     name: projects/hostproject-26a2/locations/us-central1/connectors/testserverlessvpc
```

Deployment went through fine and no errors in log encountered

```
    gcloud app deploy app.standard.yaml
```

However when I try to connect to the application endpoint , the page is not accessible with **"Server Not Found"**

I have given `VPC Access` and `Network Compute User` role to the below `App Engine Default Service account` on `VPC Host Project`

```
      <hostproject>-26a2@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
```

UPDATES

Also added below in app.yaml but no luck

```
 env_variables:
   GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB : 'anyvalue'
```

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets#making_httplib_use_sockets

Same setup for `CloudRun` and `CloudSQL` worked for me but struggling with `GAE`.  Any suggestions to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Your app.yaml file is wrong formatted. The `vpc_access_connector:` need to be at the root level. Here it's taken as an environment variable value.

```
runtime: python37

 service: appcentralpri
 env_variables:
     CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME: projectname:us-central1:mysql2
     DB_USER: guestdb
     DB_PASS: password
     DB_NAME: testdb
     DB_HOST: 10.0.100.5:3306

 vpc_access_connector:
     name: projects/hostproject-26a2/locations/us-central1/connectors/testserverlessvpc
```

Comment: Thanks . Tried but no luck

Comment: Why do you need `CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME` env var? Can you share your code where you set the connection params?

Comment: Following is the app source code https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/cloud-sql/mysql/sqlalchemy/app.standard.yaml

Comment: And the Cloud Run deployment, in the same project and by using the same connector works? Hmmmm. Strange... Can you explain why you set a peering? It's between which networks?

Comment: Not sure to follow your latest comment. Anyway, can you explain where did you deploy your working Cloud Run? With the same VPC connector and in the same project as the App Engine?

Comment: Correct...It is the same same VPC , same code  and same project for successful execution of CloudRun

Comment: In the end it seems to be code issue. We tried with a different code with the same vpc connector and is accessible now .

Comment: Good to know! Because I didn't understand the root cause!

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions you offered .